# Eject slot-loaded CD in BusyBox 1.18.4

Tags: ubuntu, mac-mini, busybox

I have a PowerPC Mac Mini that is running Ubuntu and when booted it fails to BusyBox. Problem is I cannot boot to live CD because there's a CD already in the slot and for some reason the eject applet isn't present in the version of BusyBox running. Any suggestions?

Comment: Reboot the system with the left mouse button held down?

Comment: Sweet... that worked! If you want, add it as an actual answer and I'll accept it as the answer for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some Apple equipment you can force a CD eject by holding down the left mouse button while turning on the system.